# Análises sobre os usuários do site

Tags: debate

Gostaria de compartilhar aqui uma série de análises que fiz sobre o uso do SOpt.
Qualquer sugestão é bem-vinda. Em breve posto o [link do repositório do Github](https://github.com/dfalbel/sopt) com o código para reproduzí-las. Usei como banco de dados os dumps do Stack Exchange que estão disponíveis [aqui](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Essa base tem dados até dezembro de 2016.

Se esse tipo de análise for bem vinda na comunidade continuarei fazendo sempre que possível.

Para quem gosta deste tipo de análise, o Blog do Stack Overflow tem algumas (bem mais interessantes do que essa). Veja os posts do [David Robinson](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/drobinson/) e da [Julia Silge](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/juliasilge/).

#### Cadastros no site

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até 2016, os cadastros no site eram relativamente constantes: um pouco menos de
1000 por mês. A partir de abril de 2016 ultrapassamos a barreira dos 1000 por mês e
o número de cadastros aumentou bastante desde então. No final de 2016, passamos de 2000 cadastros por mês (inclusive em Novembro chegamos em 3000).

#### Tempo desde o último acesso

Até dezembro de 2016, o site possuía 40.311 usuários cadastrados.
Destes usuários, o tempo (em dias) desde o último acesso está distribuído 
da seguinte forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, desses 40.000 usuários, 20% acessaram no último mês.
Essa tabelinha resume o que está no gráfico acima. Isso significa
que temos aproximadamente 20% dos usuários que acessam todo mês. Acho
essa taxa bem razoável.

#### Upvotes e Downvotes

Para analisar Downvotes e Upvotes vamos olhar apenas aqueles usuários que 
possuem esse direito. 125 pontos para votar negativo e 15 pontos para 
votar positivo. (sugestão do @gato e do @Victor Stafusa)

```
## # A tibble: 1 × 2
##   `>125 pontos` `>15 pontos`
##           <chr>        <chr>
## 1         6.46%        29.8%
```

Apenas 6% dos usuários têm o direito de votar negativo e 30% podem votar positivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um pouquinho mais da metade dos usuários já usou os downvotes.
Dos que já usaram, a concentração é em apenas 1 downvote.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais uma vez, um pouco mais da metade dos usuários que possuíam o direito
de votar positivo, já votaram positivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando votaram a distribuição é a seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dos usuários que votaram positivo pelo menos uma vez, 23% votaram apenas uma vez, mas
temos 29% dos usuários que votaram mais de 10 vezes. 6% dos que votaram, votaram mais de 100 vezes! Isso é bem importante! 1/3 das pessoas que votam, votam bastante! Portanto, votar
é uma barreira a ser quebrada.

É interessante ver o uso de Downvotes e Upvotes de forma conjunta. Será que usuários
que votam mais positivo também votam mais negativo? O gráfico a seguir tenta responder
um pouco disso. Aqui também usamos só os usuários que possuíam ambos os direitos (votar positivo e negativo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentre os que possuem o direito de votar negativo e positivo, metade já votou das duas formas e boa parte só deu Upvote. 9% dos que podiam votar nos dois, nunca votaram.

Outra coisa interessante é o número médio de votos dentro desses grupos.

```
## # A tibble: 4 × 5
##               grupo media_downvotes media_upvotes media_votos     n
##               <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl> <int>
## 1 Downvote & Upvote       28.129131     200.42967  228.558801  1301
## 2         Não Votou        0.000000       0.00000    0.000000   238
## 3       Só Downvote        1.166667       0.00000    1.166667    18
## 4         Só UpVote        0.000000      16.74092   16.740918  1046
```

Ou seja o que vemos é que quem votou das duas formas, em média também votou MUITO no site.

#### Reputação

A reputação dos usuários é distribuída da seguinte forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vemos que 56% dos usuários têm apenas 1 ponto de reputação, ou seja,
exceto algumas exceções, não tiveram nenhuma pergunta ou resposta na qual 
receberam votos. 29% dos usuários possui entre 1 e 100 pontos. Os usuários
que têm pelo menos 1.000 póntos representam aproximadamente 1% dos cadastrados.

Quando olhamos apenas os usuários que possuem apenas 1 ponto de reputação, podemos
identificar o seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dos usuários que tem apenas 1 ponto de reputação, 46% possuem apenas uma 
pergunta. 30% possui apenas respostas e 23% não fez nenhum post. Nenhum usuário
com 1 de reputação fez perguntas e respostas.

#### Idade

Podemos analisar também a idade dos usuários que a preencheram. No caso são 8929 que preencheram a idade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os usuários que preenchem a idade têm em média 25 anos. Mas temos bastante usuários 
entre 30 e 50 anos também.

Comment: Daniel há pessoal com quase 100 anos? :P

Comment: É.. Acho que cada um pode preencher como quiser esse campo né? :P

Comment: Se te interessar, gostaria de sugerir uma query bem interessante que achei no data.se, veja se é útil para analises futuras: http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/401402/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph

Comment: Não querendo abusar, mas fiquei curioso. Desses 56.9% dos usuários com apenas 1 ponto, você saberia dizer quantos possuem perguntas ou respostas?

Comment: @diegofm Legal! Vou fazer isso depois! AInda não mexi com a base dos posts, só a base agregada de usuários.

Comment: @Randrade anotado, vou fazer isso assim que mexer na base de posts!

Comment: Valeu @DanielFalbel. Outra coisa interessante que estávamos comentando esses dias é sobre a "média" da reputação dos usuários. Como está com uma amostragem de "ativos" (acesso nos últimos 30 dias), acho que pode ser interessante a média entre eles.

Comment: @Randrade adicionei o primeiro!

Comment: @DanielFalbel Esses "sem posts" são aqueles que não possuem perguntas e nem respostas?

Comment: Isso mesmo, são usuários que só criaram a conta!

Comment: Desse pessoal que votou ou não em perguntas ou respostas, daria para filtrar aqueles que não tem e nem nunca tiveram reputação para fazer isso? Tem muita gente que não vota simplesmente porque não tem reputação suficiente para fazer isso.

Comment: A quantidade de downvote é bem baixa, mas acho q tem que levar em consideração que para votar contra tem que ter 125 pontos de reputação e para votar a favor tem que ter 15 pontos, ou seja, esta restrição parece influenciar bastante na quantidade de downvotes.

Comment: Boa! Tinha me esquecido dessa regra, vou atualizar.

Comment: @gato Alterei a análise!

Comment: @VictorStafusa fez bastante diferença essa mudança!

Comment: [isso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWaOX.png) me lembrou a distribuição de renda no mundo, pra quem não entendeu [link](http://www.redebrasilatual.com.br/economia/2015/01/em-2016-grupo-com-1-dos-mais-ricos-do-mundo-vai-superar-os-99-mais-pobres-3617.html), e nesse mesmo gráfico deu vontade de cantar aquela musica 99% mas aquele 1% é vagabundo e fica o dia inteiro no stackoverflow :P (alias, eu faco parte desses 1% haha)

Comment: só mais uma coisa, acho que a tag "debate" esta meio off-topic

Comment: Pode editar! É que não encontrei nenhuma que encaixasse bem :(

Comment: Acho que a tag [meta-tag:debate] está sim adequada, afinal de contas a ideia provavelmente é discutir e entender o estado da comunidade e usuários através destes dados, é uma pergunta *sem resposta* ou *"sem resposta correta"*, como descrito na tag ;) @MarceloBonifazio